# Netsuite REST API for email communications

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to find where in the NetSuite REST API the communication messages are stored. I have looked at messages but the list returns 0 even though there are a lot of emails that have been sent. Guessing I'm looking in the wrong place but not sure what path the records are in.

Also once I get the emails, is there a way to extract the attachments sent in the emails to download using the API?

Thanks!

Comment: did you get any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a SuiteQL query.

```
POST https://[account].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql
Header: Prefer: transient
Body:
{
    "q": "SELECT id, authoremail, subject, datetime FROM message"
}
```

However, adding the attachments field to the search results to an unexpected error.

The record and field IDS are in the Analytics browser: https://[account].app.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_1/analytics/record/message.html.

Comment: The regular get request also works but the attachments are not available. https://[account].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/message. Are you using a custom role without a permission to view them?